# How can I get the sound back my computer?

Tags: audio

My sound was working perfectly, until I wiped my computer to factory conditions the other day. Now, the audio symbol on the bottom right of my screen has a red cross next to it.

My computer is an Acer Aspire 5551. Any additional information I can probably provide you with.

My attempts at restoring it:

So I went onto the acer help website and got onto a page with a selection of driver downloads (including blutooth drivers, card reader drivers, LAN drivers, touchpad drivers etc.), one of which was an Audio Driver, version 6.0.1.6004 of size 86.2MB, so I downloaded it. 
After my download I was directed straight to where it is in my files as the file: "Audio_Realtek_6.0.1.6004_Win7x86x64". When I click on this file it opens a huge list of 14 applications, extensions etc. and 6 more files.

I have no idea what I'm doing, and this list confuses me even more.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a file named setup.exe, click on that and follow the process through. After a reboot it usually works fine.

The reason is that what you downloaded is a zipped file, that has been extracted and what i assume you see is the folder with the installation data, it didn't actually install the driver yet. There are other ways to install a driver, but thats probably the easiest way.

Comment: There's not setup.exe but there is setup; setup.ibt; setup.inx; setup.isn; setup.iss and Usetup.iss

Comment: There's also RtlExUpd.dll ; layout.bin ; engine32 ; data2 ; data1.hdr ; data 1 ; ChCfg and then the further folders are: WDM ; Vista64 ; Vista ; MSHDQFE ; HDMI and config

Comment: Can you provide a link to what you downloaded?